# How to refresh Datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

We are trying to refresh the datatable.

We have tried this way, but it is showing error as mData not defined.

```
setTimeout(function () {
oTable.fnClearTable();
oTable.fnDraw();
oTable.fnAddData();
}, 3000);
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
"bProcessing": true,
"bJQueryUI": true,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"sAjaxSource": "../controllers/JQGridBOTMonitoringDashboard.php",
"aoColumns": [{
        "mData": "bot"
    }, {
        "mData": "ip_address"
    }, {
        "mData": "status",
        "fnRender": function (obj) {
            var status = obj.aData.status;
            if (status == 'online') {
                obj.oSettings.aoColumns[obj.iDataColumn].sClass = "greenBackground"
            } else {
                obj.oSettings.aoColumns[obj.iDataColumn].sClass = "redBackground"
            }
            return status;
        }
    }, {
        "mData": "os"
    }, {
        "mData": "os_version"
    }, {
        "mData": "last_execution_time"
    },

    {
        "sTitle": "ACTIONS",
        "sClass": "center",
        "sDefaultContent": '<a class="bot_show"><img src="images/button_view.png"/></a>',
        "bSortable": false,
        "bSearchable": false,
        "fnRender": function (obj) {
            var id = obj.aData.id;
            obj.oSettings.aoColumns[obj.iDataColumn].sClass = id;
        }
    }
]
});
```

Comment: Have you tried fnReloadAjax(url)

Comment: Or fnStandingRedraw()?

Comment: @mainguy
i have tried 
oTable.fnStandingRedraw();
both methods are throwing error that they are not a functions

Comment: Then they can't find the plugin in their scope. Make oTable global by leaving out the VAR and call the function AFTER dataTables has been initialized.

Comment: @mainguy sure i will try it and let you know.. Thanks a lot..

Comment: @mainguy still same problem persists.. :(

Comment: @mainguy i am calling the fnReloadAjax in $(document).ready(function()) is this the problem???

Comment: Could be, dataTables may have not finished it's initialization or it's initial ajax request. Put it outside document ready and first try to start it with some button clicks. Then, when it does not throw errors move it to your timeout and be gentle with the timing. Its a tremendous amount of dom manipulations that happens on init. So give it some time.

Comment: @mainguy sure and thank you very much for your suggestions and caveats